# Issues when changing to Sculpting Mode

Tags: sculpting

So as a lot of people, I am going through Blender Gurus donut videos. I have gotten to the part where we change to sculpting mode. When I change over, the icing on my donut disappears and all I can see are the "drooping" parts I made in edit mode. I am sure this is an easy fix that I just dont know where to click a box or something.